# Cursor grabbing style not work in Electron JS

Tags: electron

I'm developing the App with ElectronJS. I wont to do some element draggable by JS-manipulation. During element grabbing i want change cursor view by style cursor: grabbing, but it doesn't working.

This are my styles:

```
.photo-editor-crop-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid blueviolet;
  cursor: grab;
}

.photo-editor-crop-frame:active {
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  cursor: -moz-grabbing;
  cursor: grabbing;
}
```

These styles don't work only in Electron, they work well in Chrome browser. I tryed to use browser prefixes, but it not resolve.

How can i fix the problem with grabbing style in ElectronJS?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by accident, the cursor will not be changed when DevTools is opened. Close DevTools and behaviour became standard.